# Cannot connect to mongoDB Atlas using mongoose : { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Although I am not the first on Stackoverflow not to be able to connect to mongoDB atlas using mongoose, no one seems to have my specific error:

> { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server
>   [cluster0-shard-00-00-shqnc.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect
>   [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to
>   cluster0-shard-00-00-shqnc.mongodb.net:27017 closed]

Here's how my server is set-up:

**Keys.js**

```
module.exports = {
  mongoURI:
    "mongodb+srv://Ahmed:<MyMongoDBAtlasPWD>@cluster0-shqnc.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
};
```

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();

// DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("MongoDB connected!");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello");
});

//process.env.Port is for Heroku
const port = process.env.Port || 5000;
// `` ES6 Template literal is used so that we can put a variable inside the String
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

And this is the code suggested by the MongoDB atlas website to be used:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://Ahmed:<password>@cluster0-shqnc.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

But, since I don't want to use mongoClient but rather mongoose, I am having some trouble and I cannot see why the code doesn't work;

**EDIT 1:** I have managed to connect using the Shell command(Check-out my answer). However, connecting through the app doesn't work and gives a different error:

> { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server
>   [cluster0-shard-00-01-shqnc.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect
>   [MongoError: bad auth Authentication failed.]

**EDIT 2:** I made a stupid mistake. I've forgotten to remove <> from the . All is good now.

Comment: have you made sure that the ip addres from where you are trying to connect is whitelisted in atlas?

Comment: @AshishModi yes it's done

Comment: try to connect it from your mongo shell- like `mongo yourconnectionstringhere` and see what do you get

Comment: @AshishModi It gives the same error

Comment: so problem is not in the code, it is in your mongodb atlas setup.

Comment: @AshishModi okay thanks I will check it out

Comment: just to double check you have whitelisted your public IP? You can find that by googling "what is my ip"

Comment: @AshishModi I have solved it. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that I was trying to connect using my MongoDB Atlas account password instead of the user password. Yes, those are 2 different things.
**1. Click on Database Access**
[image]

**2. Edit the current user and modify the password** 
[image]

**3. Use that password to connect to MongoDB Atlas**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have whitelisted your public IP. You can find that by googling "what is my ip".